# recent change to messages app for emoji and birthday cake icons

Tags: stock-android

[image]

A recent update has these annoying ions show up in 1st grade reader font size when I go to the attachment mode, and I was trying to see if they can be either disabled entirely or at least moved to thebottom out of the way. I want the picture attachment back on top the way it used to be before the cartoon characters took over.
The way it's set up is ridiculous looking.
Is there any secret seeing to get rid of this?

Answer (score 0):

Root your phone.
No need to worry
And change these fonts from another device where they show well

```
/system/fonts/NotoColorEmoji.ttf
/system/fonts/AndroidEmoji.ttf
```

Set their permissions to `chmod 0644` *-rw-r--r-*
They will be back to normal or if you can install twrp or any other custom recovery i can send you a whole Fonts.zip flashable via recovery to fix this issue